# WAMP, Windows 10 : #2002 - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. &mdash;

Tags: windows, phpmyadmin, wamp

I tried to login to phpMyAdmin in WAMP + Windows 10. But I got the following errors when I tried to login as root ( no password )

> #2002 - No connection could be made because the target machine
>   actively refused it. — The server is not responding (or the
>   local server's socket is not correctly configured).
>
> mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No connection could be made
>   because the target machine actively refused it.

It will be great if someone can help me out. Thanks.

PS : The WAMP icon is Orange in colour

PS 2 : I closed Skype from Task manager using End Task

Comment: Are you trying to connect from the same machine which contains the database?

Comment: Yes, a single machine is all that is involved.

Comment: Are you able to login from the **cmd** or **powershell** command line using the **mysql** command?

Answer (score 0):

Open my.ini file by left clicking wampp and opening MySQL menu. Search socket and write

```
socket = /tmp/mysql.sock
```

And save it.